# QRCodeDecoderLibrary для Selenium на C#. Распознавание QR-Кода

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Не могу понять как работает библиотека `QRCodeDecoderLibrary` для `Selenium` на C#. Нужно распознать текст с картинки QR-Кода и передать его дальше

Есть файл на диске, передаю путь к этому файлу, но постоянно ошибки.
Последняя была: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот **код**:

```
string FileAdr = $"C:/Users/kuzya/Downloads/{fileName}-qr.png";
QRDecoder decoder = new QRDecoder();
var res = decoder.ImageDecoder(new Bitmap(FileAdr));
// var res = decoder.ImageDecoder(new Bitmap Image.FromFile(FileAdr));
string link = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res[0]);
Log.Info($"{res}, {link}");
File.Delete($@"{FileAdr}");
```

Comment: эту ошибку решите и будете новый вопрос задавать про другую ошибку? выкладывайте сразу все

Comment: относительно этой ошибки - надо прояснить, почему `res` пустой. поставьте брекпоинт на строке инициализации, посмотрите что происходит

Comment: возможно у меня ошибка в синтаксисе, в res(это массив) аргументом приходит Bitmap, может у меня ошибка в задании адреса к картинке, это я и хочу узнать. Если эту ошибку решу, то следующее действие - это декодирование в текст первого полученного элемента res

Comment: `Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\qr.png");
 var res = QRcode.ImageDecoder(image1);
 string link = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(res[0]);`   точно такая же ошибка, у меня будет если я немного поменяю код. Так я точно вижу , что Bitmap у меня определился, но res также  null